# Axios call timeout on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, axios

I make a call with axios in my react app, hosted on netfliy, to delete a recipe in the database.

```
const handleDelete = async () => {
        if (warn) {
            await axios.delete('https://foodeii.herokuapp.com/api/delete/rec', { data: { id: props.recipe[0].ID } }).then((response) => {
                console.log('Recipe deleted successfully.')
                goBack();
            })
        } else {
            setWarn(true);
            alert('You will not be able to restore this recipe after deleting.')
        }
    }
```

This is my express server on heroku:

```
// DELETE
app.delete('/api/delete/rec', (req, res) => {
    const recipe = req.body.id;

    const sqlSelect = `DELETE FROM recipes WHERE ID = ${recipe}`;
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

const recipe is a simple ID of the recipe in the DB. the DB is TINY with only 3 recipes.

When I go to my dashboard all the GET requests are working perfectly fine within seconds.

But on this delete query I get timeout at heroku, code=12 and I don't even get to see that console log in axios call .

Why do I keep on getting a timeout on heroku? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did not include res.send() !! Fixed